# How to build a linked list using two inputs

Tags: java

I have having an issue figuring out how to create a linked list of objects created with two inputs. It is not printing as it should be. I wasn't sure how to initiate the initial headObj. I think that might be causing the issue?

```
public class ContactList {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  int i;
  String name;
  String number;
  int counter;

  ContactNode headObj = new ContactNode(" ");
  ContactNode newObject;
  ContactNode prevObject;
  
  
  prevObject = headObj;
  for (i = 0; i<3; i++){
    
    name = scnr.next();
    number = scnr.next();
    newObject = new ContactNode(name, number);
    prevObject.insertAfter(newObject);
    prevObject = newObject;
  }
  
  newObject = headObj;
  
   counter = 0;
  
  while (newObject != null) {
     counter++;
     System.out.print("Person " + counter + " ");
     newObject.printContactNode();
     newObject = newObject.getNext();
     
   }
  }
}
```

The result is supposed to be:

Person 1: Roxanne Hughes, 443-555-2864

Person 2: Juan Alberto Jr., 410-555-9385

Person 3: Rachel Phillips, 310-555-6610

But it is printing as:

Person 1  , null

Person 2 Roxanne, Hughes

Person 3 443-555-2864, Juan

Person 4 Alberto, Jr.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `nextLine()` to scan the current line of characters, because `next()` method finds and returns the next complete token from your specified Scanner object, which from `System.in` so it is really depends on how you input the characters.

for more information about `Scanner` class here is the reference [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).
and also another reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) from SO about Scanner in that you need to know.